# Debian is not bootable after install Open GL Libs

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, opengl, steam

I tried to install Steam, but the Open GL Libraries seems to break my system. I'm running Debian Jessie (Kernel 3.16.0.4) with Gnome on a 64-bit Laptop. My Laptop is a HP Pavilion 17, so Windows was preinstalled and I installed Debian later.

lscpu:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            21
Model:                 19
Model name:            AMD A10-5750M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               1400.000
CPU max MHz:           2500.0000
CPU min MHz:           1400.0000
BogoMIPS:              4990.34
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             16K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              2048K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Installing `libgl1-fglrx-glx-i386` and `steam` (as explained [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Steam#Installation)) returns no errors, but when I restart my computer, I get that grey "Ooops something went wrong!" screen. Then, I have to uninstall the Open GL libs to make my system work.

I didn't find any similar issue using Google. Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to console mode  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

Remove steam and `libgl1-fglrx-glx-i386`

```
sudo apt-get remove libgl1-fglrx-glx-i386
sudo apt-get remove steam
```

Install steam:

```
wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb
dpkg -i steam.deb
apt-get -f install
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
```

install 32bit libraries:

```
apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386
```

Reinstall `libgl1-fglrx-glx-i386`

```
apt-get install  libgl1-fglrx-glx-i386
```

Comment: Nope, same problem :(

Comment: remove `libgl1-fglrx-glx-i386` and type `systemctl start gdm.service`